# How can I save Checkbox selection in qt c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to develop an application with QT C++. I added a checkBox. How can I make my checkBox be in the last selection when I close my app and open it again. For example, if the checkbox was selected before the application was closed, I want it to be selected when the application runs again. If it wasn't selected before closing, it should come back unselected when it runs again. How can I do that?

Comment: Just store the checkbox selection to `QSettings`. You can store the value to settings in window destructor and restore it in the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the value of the checkbox when your app shuts down. Save the value somewhere, like; `QSettings`, a custom file, windows registry, etc. When your application starts, read the stored value and set the checkbox state to match.